# How to create a numpy array of a given type with numba

Tags: python, python-3.x, numba

Since Numba 0.19 one is able to explicitly create numpy arrays in nopython mode. How can I create an array of a given type?

```
from numba import jit
import numpy as np

@jit(nopython=True)
def f():
    a = np.zeros(5, dtype = np.int)
```

The above code fails with the following error

```
TypingError: Failed at nopython (nopython frontend)
Undeclared Function(<built-in function zeros>)(int32, Function(<class 'int'>))
File "<ipython-input-4-3169be7a8201>", line 6
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `numba` dtypes instead of `numpy`

```
import numba
import numpy as np

@numba.njit
def f():
    a = np.zeros(5, dtype=numba.int32)
    return a

In [8]: f()
Out[8]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I was intrigued by your use of njit instead of jit, so I went to the documentation and found that njit is equivalent to jit(nopython=True)! Cool!

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned that. I'm happy I could help!

Answer (score 1):

In python 2.7 it seems that np.int does work.

As for the workaround from dlenz, I'd like to point that using np.int32 does work as well... with the added advantage that the code will work without modifications if you want to remove numba.njit at some point for whatever reason.